# my header component of NativeBase result is empty and not on top

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

when I use header component from [nativeBase](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#header-icon-headref)  :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3011.png)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import changeNavigationBarColor,{ showNavigationBar } from 'react-native-navigation-bar-color';
import { Container, Header, Left, Body, Right, Button, Icon, Title } from 'native-base';

import { main, discoverPage } from './../../assets/style'
import HeaderOfPage from './../../components/Header'


export default class Splash extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            showNavigationBar()
        },200)
        changeNavigationBarColor('#1f2128', true)
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <Container style={[main.Container,{backgroundColor:'#1f2128'}]}>
                <Header>
                  <Left>
                    <Button transparent>
                      <Icon name='arrow-back' />
                    </Button>
                  </Left>
                  <Body>
                    <Title>Header</Title>
                  </Body>
                  <Right>
                    <Button transparent>
                      <Icon name='menu' />
                    </Button>
                  </Right>
                </Header>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}
```

I don't know why, maybe because I use [changeNavigationBarColor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-navigation-bar-color)
someone can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you give Flex in main.Container ?
This seems like an issue from the style in Container component.

Comment: yes `flex:1,justifyContent : 'center' , alignItems : 'center',`

Answer (score 0):

In Native Base +3 versions Header component is deprecated. If you search on official docs. You can can find this info:

> With v3 we have removed the Header as it can be easily built using HStack. You can checkout its recipe [here](https://docs.nativebase.io/buildingAppBar).